# Blue screen code: memory management

Tags: memory, motherboard, bsod

I bought a new PC a week ago and yesterday it suddenly turned blue screen. 
I have tried everything I can (don't overclock CPU,change RAM speed,
check the motherboard and RAM compatibility etc.), but it still turned blue.

- CPU: Ryzen 7 1700 3.0 GHz
- Motherboard: MSI B350
- Memory: Corsair 16GB (2 × 8 GB) DDR4 DRAM 3000 MHz C15 Memory Kit – Red LED (CMU16GX4M2C3000C15R)
- Video Card: MSI GeForce GTX 1060, 6 GB
- Storage: Crucial BX300 2.5-inch SSD 240 GB

and I tried Memtest; it shows
[image]

There are no red line errors but shows lots of errors. 
What does it mean? And what should I do to fix this problem?

If you need any more detail, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You probabbly have bad hardware.

Does memory need to be installed in pairs?  If not:

Pull one memory module.  Repeat test.  Reinsert memory module, pull other memory module.  Repeat test.  If it only fails the test with one module, that is the bad module.  If it fails with both, most likely the RAM is good and something else is wrong.  The something else could be the motherboard, or the power supply, or BIOS settings.